# Laravel: Fetch with where filter on "with"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel you can fetch a related database entry in one query with the with method like this:

```
$customer = Customer::with('user')->where([
    'id' =>'1'
])->first();
```

Which will return a customer and it's related user object. Is it possible to apply a filter to this with item? I thought that this would be possible:

```
$customer = Customer::with('user')->where([
    'id' =>'1',
    'users.status' => 'activated'
])->first();
```

But that does not seem to work, it tries to find a column "users.status" instead of a column status in the users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Eager loading constraints. It allows you to perform queries on related models.

Like this:

```
$customer = Customer::with(['user' => function($query){
    $query->where('status', 'activated'); //in the user table
}])->where('id', '1')->first(); //in the customer table
```

You can read the eager load constaints part for more informations:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Answer (score 2):

You could write your query this way:

```
$customer = Customer::with(['user' => function($q){
    $q->whereStatus('activated'); 
}])->find(1);
```

Assuming your primary key is `1`, you don't need to use `where('id','=','1')->get()`, you can simply use `find(1)` and for selecting only some records for related table you use construction as `with` passing also closure.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in some of my code in addition to MrShibby's answer.
This is how I do it, maybe you find that useful.

```
$activities = Activity::with('user')
     ->with(array('images'=>function($query){
         $query->orderBy('sort','ASC');
     }))
     ->with(array('images.titles'=>function($query){
        $query->orderBy('language_id','ASC');
    }))                
     ->with(array('contents'=>function($query){
         $query->orderBy('language_id','ASC');
     }))
     ->with(array('titles'=>function($query){
         $query->orderBy('language_id','ASC');
     }))             
     ->where('user_id',$user_id)
     ->whereRaw('DATE(NOW()) between online_from and online_until')
     ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
     ->get();
```